# How to install package using pip and save name to file to install it later

Tags: python, installation, package

I'd like to do something like `pip install requests --save packages.txt` so I could have list of all I used and later I could just `pip -r install packages.txt` when I clone it from repository.

Comment: What about `pip freeze` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `freeze` to dump all the installations to your .txt file as:

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And, you can run following later when needed :

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: But I see that I can not save specific package while installing, but only all in virtual environment or global packages

Comment: The concept is making packages of virtualenv to be runnable at another end. For that, all the packages should be shared, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

pip install package --download="path to directory"

pip install --no-index --find-links="path to directory" package_name

**Note**: `pip download` replaces the --download option to `pip install`, which is now deprecated and will be removed in pip 10.

Comment: When I use with pip3 "DEPRECATION: pip install --download has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Pip now has a download command that should be used instead."

Comment: @Meroz i have updated my answer , try this.   refer https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/#options

Comment: I don't fully understand you answer. Should it look like ` pip3 install requests download "pack.txt"`? `pip3 download requests` is downloading this package bu I need only name of the package save to the file